# Proving rank of linear operator equals the rank of the B matrix of linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

I am new to linear algebra, and I am struggling with this question. Any help would be really appreciated.

Let  $B$ and  $C$ both be bases for $\Bbb R^n$ and let $L: \Bbb R^n → \Bbb R^n$ be a linear operator. Prove that $\text{rank}([L]_B) = \dim(\text{Range}(L))$

What I have concluded so far is that we are trying to prove that $\text{rank}([L]_B) = \text{rank}(L)$, but I also do not know how to prove this.

I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: There is an isomorphism between the vectors and its coordinates. Try to think that the image of $L$ is the span of of vecter whose coordinate is the columns of $[L]_B$.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My issue is that my course has not brought up the term isomorphism yet. Is there any way to prove this without that term or idea?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** using the definition of the matrix of a linear map, you can show first that the range of $L$ is the vector subspace of $\Bbb R^n$ generated by the columns of $[L]_B$.